# Why did the shields behave this way in 'Star Trek Beyond'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In Star Trek Beyond, why were the Enterprise's shields

> so useless against Krall's swarm ships, which seem to just fly through them as if they weren't even there?

In all the previous movies, the shields have always protected ships to some extent. The exceptions were Wrath of Khan where the Reliant was able to get shots in before Enterprise raised them, and Generations where the Klingons found the shield frequencies.

But in this movie the writers seem to have no knowledge of how shields work and the swarm ships (which were physical objects that could have been easily blocked by shields) seem to just fly through them.

I can understand that the writers wanted Krall to win the battle but they could have made it work according to the Star Trek universe rules, meaning get the shields get weakened and then penetrated.

Comment: Bear in mind that *Star Trek Beyond* is set in an alternate timeline to the old films/TV shows. I can't remember to what extent we've seen shields used in the 3 films released in this new timeline, but is it possible that the shields are only able to block energy based weapons now? Meaning physical objects can just pass straight through?

Comment: @DrRDizzle we have seen similar happenings already in tng and also ds9. Ramming with shuttlesize+ sized objects seems to be working quite good in all of star trek

Comment: Related, possible dupe; [How vulnerable to physical hits are Federation ships?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93720/how-vulnerable-to-physical-hits-are-federation-ships)

Comment: These are ships made specifically to board shielded ships.

Comment: @Axelrod - Really? All evidence suggests that they're there to defend a mining outpost.

Comment: @Valorum They're specially-made swarm ships that don't match the architecture of any other ships seen in the movie series. We know they're automated, we know they're something that no one had seen before on the Enterprise, and we know that crashing into things to get inside was their MO. Edit: they were apparently left there by the original inhabitants, so that's just their current usecase, not necessarily their intended use.

Comment: @Valorum Also notable: the swarm ships were clearly *designed* to work that way, albeit possibly not on the same sort of target, since they open up like a hollow point and give the cockpit access to the inside of whatever they penetrate.

Comment: *"That's what the swarm is – sophisticated mining equipment. All those soldiers were just worker drones. Krall turned them into an army, and turned the swarm into a weapon. There's all this great backstory to be explored in the novelisation!”*" - Simon Pegg; http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-trek-beyond-justin-lin-simon-pegg/

Comment: VOY offers something similar too, in at least one episode (I think it's the one where Kes travels backwards in time, but that might be just a backreference), and the handwavium explanation then is that the incoming object is able to pass through the shields because it is in a state of temporal flux. I haven't seen *Star Trek Beyond* so have no idea if that might possibly apply here.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - There's no indication (whatsoever) that the swarm ships are out of phase temporally.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The shields are [definitely up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEmGpXOLFBk), but the swarm ships seem to be completely unaffected.

As far as can be told, there's no explanation offered *why* this is the case but the Conn Officer seems ***quite surprised that they're useless***, suggesting that they should have proven more resilient.

> **Chekov:** *Shield frequencies are having no effect, Captain.*

Comment: I like this answer best because it mentions Chekov surprise at the shields not working. Which seems to indicate that shields "should" work against this type of attack.

Comment: @AbuMariam Tbh it takes me by surprise but then again they ALWAYS tried to use shields despite their low/to none effect. That means either shields have more effect than we see from our pov as watchers. OR the starfleet guys are not used to ramming techniques (which I take is quite unusual in that universe so far at least)

Comment: @Thomas - I suspect there's a writer's reason out there, but it's not been revealed yet).

Comment: This is called "hanging a lantern" on the problem. Clearly the producers decided that we did not need a technobabble explanation for the shields being so useless, but needed us to know that — in-universe — there was one. We just don't know what it was (and neither do the characters, for that matter). And so we move on with the story.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - More usually a "*lampshade*" than a lantern, but you're completely right. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging

Comment: SPOILER: The reason shields are unaffected is likely due to the villain's true identity, and knowledge of Starfleet technology.

Comment: @liesmith - I prefer to stick to evidence-based answers. The other have already covered fan-theory pretty well.

Comment: @Valorum: From that page: _«This practice is also known as [..] "hanging a lantern on it"»_

Comment: To be fair, Liesmith's and Paul's theory is very strong when you consider how much was made of Krall's hacking into Starfleet. I hadn't thought of this at the time, but I believe they have a high chance of being correct. Whether that makes it worthy of inclusion in an answer, though, I couldn't say.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - And while true, that phrase was popularised in the 1950s.

Comment: @Liesmith I think its less the villain's knowledge of the technology and potentially more his current extended knowledge of the starfleet systems due to described intellgence gathering

Comment: @Thomas I think shields are something of a victim of the "Worf Effect" - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheWorfEffect - presumably the cases where they successfully stop problems from occurring aren't interesting enough to show on-screen.

Comment: @NateDiamond: Knowledge of the technology is what enabled the intelligence gathering ;) (Although I thought this was the weakest part of the film's plot based on how out-of-date the guy was by this point)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Definitely true. I was more giving specifics as opposed to general "knowledge" leading to the specific "knowledge of this specific ship". It was shown that he had specific knowledge due to intelligence gathering, so this can directly be correlated to specific knowledge of the ship, which I think is a worthwhile distinction.

Comment: @Nate: Got ya. :)

Answer (score 32):

As I haven't seen the film itself, just the trailer, I'm making assumptions on that one (although I don't think they would change).

Shields in Star Trek reduce the damage that beam and projectile weapons (phasers, disruptors, torpedoes) do to ships, and negate damage from small asteroids by pushing them aside (navigational deflectors).

The swarm ships, though, seem to be of at least shuttle size, and numerous times kamikaze/ramming attacks from ships of that size have proven to be too much for the shields to do much about.

This has happened time and again in almost every property of Star Trek:

- *The Next Generation*: Multiple times in the show shuttlecraft or whole starships crashed into the Enterprise; mostly during time paradox episodes, as it almost always resulted in the destruction of the Enterprise.
- *The Next Generation*: Worf flies a shuttle inside the Borgs' shields to get on board a Borg cube.
- *Deep Space Nine*: In the episode where the Dominion declares war on the Federation, a Galaxy class ship travels through the wormhole to the Gamma quadrant and gets destroyed by a single Jem’Hadar fighter ramming it.
- *Star Trek: First Contact*: The Defiant is ordered on a ramming course into a Borg cube (not shown on screen due to interference). The Defiant would have probably caused massive damage to the cube despite the cube’s strong shields.
- *Star Trek: Nemesis*: The Enterprise rams a Reman super warship. No advantage due to shields for either of the two sides.
- *Star Trek (2009)*: The wreck of a starship damages the outer hull; shields have no visible effect.

So in essence, it seems that with an impacting object above a specific size and speed, the shields become useless or reduce the damage only minimally.

Comment: You could add _ST:Nemesis_ to the list: Picard has the Enterprise ram Shinzon's Warbird.

Comment: You could also add the time in ST:TNG when Data and Worf use a shuttle to get inside the Borg's shield so that they can warp onto the ship.

Comment: This seems like the best answer, and the only answer needed. I don't think Star Trek has ever given the impression that shields could prevent a ship from being crashed into by another ship (or by anything else sufficiently large and heavy).

Comment: @TheBloodyPoet added it good point

Comment: @sgr tnx added it (forgot the line about the shields bak then

Comment: @recognizer yeah although they always try to raise shields there. what is also interesting according to the accepted answer they sounded surprised in universe that shields dont have an effect

Comment: By the way, looking over your answer, I think some people may dispute the size of the swarm ships. They are rather cramped inside, but they're definitely at least a few times greater in diameter than a torpedo. I doubt one would fit into the cargo area of a shuttle, though, and that's enough to call them shuttle-sized to me.

Comment: _"The Defiant would have probably caused massive damage to the cube"_ I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: In the *Nemesis* example, I guess the ships were in a stalemate situation, both mostly out of energy, thus no proper shields (only structural integrity fields)

Comment: If this is "the answer", then that ridiculously dense swarm of asteroids should have ground the Enterprise up long before they made it to the planet (which is uncharted yet miraculously has a name).

Comment: @jeff like mentioned I didnt watch the film itself so far. but if its asteroids you are talking about this is where things get tricky as the navigational deflectors should move them out of the way. With ships on the other hand the navigational def. doesnt work as they move under their own powers and thus try to resist any attempt to alter their course. That is at least how i always understood things there.

Comment: If shuttles are so effective, why aren't they mass-produced and used as ammo?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman In starfleet battles (a star trek based tabletop game) it is a tactic to be used (although the shuttles are a primary target there for that reason). :D

Comment: I don't this is a good explanation. I think shields will prevent any physical object from passing them (be they beam weapons or actual ships). If you also recall ST6 when Excelsior encountered the cloud wave which came when Praxis exploded, Captiain Sulu cried out for "shields". As was stated in the accepted answer, there was probably an "in universe" reason but neither we nor the crew knew it. Maybe it was as Paul suggested that Krall found out the Enterprise's shield frequencies. But if something like that can be snooped I think it is speaks poorly for Star-fleet security.

Comment: @AbuMariam according to memory beta the shields in universe got overloaded through the number of ships hitting them. Which is in essence what I meant with my post. The ships can stop asteroids, beams, torpedoes,.... But they can get overwhelmed even while up. Shuttle+ size seems to be where most ships get problems (or prove completely ineffective). Thus 1 or 2 shuttle sized hits COULD have been blocked or damage reduced by shields, but the mass was what made the difference there. And in other cases just the size of the object.

Answer (score 22):

There is a line in the movie mentioning the ineffectiveness of the shields against the swarm ships — annoyingly I can’t remember it, but [it is mentioned in this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/4u7m22/loved_star_trek_beyond_one_question_do_the/d5niaeg), which claims the line mentions shield frequencies.

As you noted, there’s precedent from *Generations* that shields can be ineffective if the enemy knows their frequency. As you’ll also remember from later in the movie, Krall is actually

> a former Starfleet captain

and has been

> accessing lots of Starfleet information already, including Captain Kirk’s personal log.

As such, although it’s not made clear in the movie, I think it’s reasonable to assume that:

1. Krall has discovered the Enterprise’s shield frequency and used that to allow the swarm ships to pass through; and
2. the writers of the movie [actually do know](http://screenrant.com/retro-references-star-trek-beyond/?view=all) [a couple of things](http://collider.com/simon-pegg-star-trek-beyond-interview/) about Star Trek, including how shields are meant to work.

Comment: Yes exactly, Krall knows all about the Enterprise as he was monitoring starfleet data and his agent was used to lure it to him, and as we've seen in other Trek sources (remember they used to have to keep cycling the phaser and shield frequencies when fighting the Borg), knowing the shield frequency allows you to get weapons through it.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: Yeah, I often use hundred-year-old technology to hack into the encrypted communications and databases of my adversaries quite easily :-P

Comment: @Jeff: no-one said it was easy Jeff! Using [hundred-year-old technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) for [computer hacks](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2995426/malware-cybercrime/headphones-can-be-used-to-hack-a-smartphone-report-says.html) never is.

Comment: @Jeff : The thing is, yes, the technology he started with was 100+ yrs old. However he also has had 100+ years to keep up with Starfleet...

Answer (score 3):

Shields aren't designed,nor are they capable of protection against high-speed ram attacks.  That's why navigation deflectors are used to clear out debris in the path of FTL ships.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up your statements?  While it seems like a reasonable hypothesis, it would add credibility if you could give some in-universe or official explanation that agrees with your assessment.

Comment: @JaneS - User MichaelHancock made the point (in a deleted answer) that "**in regards to navigational deflectors, check out the Voyager episode "Year of Hell". When Voyager's deflector is offline and they run into a meteor shower the ship starts being hit. Janeway then forces her way into deflector control, realigns the emitters and the ship is safe again."**

Comment: Nope. If that was the case, some bright spark would have invented a frag torpedo, and suddenly shields would be useless. Navigational deflectors are weak shields designed only to protect against small, low-energy collisions, and thus use far less energy, which is why they are used for navigation rather than full-blown combat shields.

Answer (score 3):

This happens fairly commonly in Star Trek, in reverse. Firing on a Borg ship usually only works once or twice due to them somehow figuring out the firing frequencies and adjusting their shields accordingly.

Also, in the most high-tech of starships, it's possible to transport people even though shields are up, even though enemies can't teleport through the shields, suggesting that if the frequencies of the shield is known it's possible to bypass them. While any random object might not be able to get through, ships with specific enhancements to negate common Starfleet shield frequencies, on the other hand should have no such restriction...

Answer (score 0):

It never made any sense that Trek shields weren't capable of blocking kinetic attacks.
Starship shields work very similarly to internal forcefields (which are more than capable of preventing any and all kinds of attacks).
We've seen Worf rig up  a personal shield in TNG from a commbadge that managed to deflect several bullets.

Shuttles in comparison to a much larger starship would have a similar effect... they would run up against the shields and would effectively ram INTO the shields without penetrating them.

With the case of DS9... we do have at least 1 example of Jem'Hadaar kamikaze runs not being effective.
The Dominion's first attack (with the Cardassians) on DS9.
There was a scene where a Jem'Hadaar attack ship attempted to ram the station... and we've seen it clearly impact the station's shields without penetrating them (the station was at the time under heavy assault from the Dominion/Cardassian fleet no less).

In the episode where a Jem'Hadaar attack ship rammed a Galaxy class - by that point the crew already turned the shields off as they were useless against polaron beams and shuffled the energy into reinforcing Phasers instead.
That's why the attack ship was able to successfully take out the Odyssey.

As for subsequent scenes where we've seen Dominion kamikaze runs being effective... well, most of those scenes already occurred with both sides being under heavy fire and shields being mostly or completely drained.

DS9 VFX department was almost criminally negligent in showing shields during fleet battles - which is one of the reasons why single weapon shots would start taking out ships or make large holes in them (which simply wouldn't have happened that fast - but I guess that for the sake of the story, we've seen an abridged version of the battle where you get the general idea - although, with fleets, I think what the VFX team decided to do instead of showing shields glowing, they ended up just dissipating the shots into the hull without them doing anything).

Star Trek Nemesis however somehow managed to completely ignore a layered shield system on the Scimitar which allowed the Enterprise to get through as if they weren't there.
Though, that movie also showcased skin-tight shields, which might explain why the shield wasn't immediately visible on other sections of the Scimitar (because energy weapons seem to be dissipated throughout the shield, while a starship kamikaze run produces a more localized effect).

Still doesn't make sense to be honest, because the Scimitar's shields should have been A LOT more effective - but we don't know what Picard might have done off-screen to negate Scimitar's shields.

As for 'Year of Hell'... those were micro-meteroids... so navigational shields are used for moving space debris (matter) that travels at very high speeds out of the way of the ship primarily (although, they seem to simply REPEL and alter the trajectory of the said objects as opposed to allowing them to make contact in the first place), but they do seem to be effective against energy based attacks too (TNG mentioned that lasers aren't enough to even penetrate navigational shields)... just nowhere near on the level of actual defensive shields.

As for Beyond movie swarm... the crew did act surprised the shields were not effective, indicating that they should have been.

Its one of the things I don't like about these new movies... shields for example are portrayed as non-existent actually. If you look at the battle between the Enterprise and Vengeance for instance (Star Trek Darkness), you'd see that each phaser shot and torpedo makes contact on the hull itself as if the shields aren't there (and Kirk did order shields up with enough time just before the Vengeance started attacking).

Now, this could be explained in another way: the Vengeance was a top-secret Federation ship, and therefore could have had Enterprise shield frequencies, making them useless against their weapons.

But this doesn't seem likely... just as unlikely as the premise that detonating several torpedoes INSIDE the Vengeance wouldn't destroy it.
Ok... starships are highly advanced and made from really tough materials, so even these torpedoes could easily destroy a planetary surface in a few shots, on starships (even interiors) they wouldn't necessarily incur too much damage... however, 1 torpedo was detonated in close proximity to 71 others.
Durability aside, that SHOULD have destroyed the Vengeance right then and there, or at least vaporize an entire secondary hull, breach all its way to the Warp core and take out the entire ship (unless the ship had advanced internal forcefields capable of limiting such damage, but generally, I would imagine that the Vengeance's warp core detonating from inside it would be more than enough to overload any such defenses).

So, we have expamples of Trek shields being very effective against kinetic and kamikaze attacks (not just energy based weapons).
Problem is that in the case of the movies, things like this get overlooked for the sake of increasing the drama.

In 'Beyond' though, Krall already had information about Yorktown and the Enterprise, meaning he probably had what he needed to increase the swarm's effectiveness in negating the Enterprise shields (likely by modifying the swarm fleet with adaptive shield frequencies that would respond to several different Federation shield frequencies) - although its still a bit dubious as to how he was able to penetrate Federation comm frequencies and acquire sensitive data.
Advanced tech will take you only so far, and the Federation by the mid 23rd century already had it's technology from a mixture of dozens of different alien species.
I find it unlikely that such versatility and combination could be easily penetrated by Krall even if he did have underlying understanding of Starfleet - but as I said, things changed radically.